Can't get Django view to never cache when accessing via browser
I have a Django app hosted on a Linux server served by NGINX.
A view called DashboardView displays data from a Postgresql database. This database gets routinely updated by processes independent of the Django app.
In order for the latest data to always be displayed I have set the view to never cache. However this doesn't seem to be applied when viewing in the browser. The only way I can force through the view to show the updated data is via a GUNICORN restart on the server.
When I look at the the Network details in Google Chrome devtools everything looks set correctly. See below the cache control details shown.
max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Please see Django code below setting never cache on the DashboardView.
Could the issue be related to the get_context_data method on the CBV?
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache


class NeverCacheMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(NeverCacheMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class DashboardView(NeverCacheMixin, TemplateView):
        
    template_name = 'example/dashboard/dashboard.html'
     
    # product queryset   
    # get the first and last date in the data set, and derive all other dates from it    
    queryset_product_all = ViewDashboard.objects.all()
  
    first_product_date = queryset_product_all.order_by("position_date").values('position_date').first()['position_date']     
    latest_product_date = ViewDashboard.objects.values("position_date").aggregate(latest_product_date=Max('position_date'))['latest_product_date']   
    latest_product_date_str = latest_product_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")      
    start_itd_str = first_product_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  
    start_mth_str = date(latest_product_date.year, latest_product_date.month, 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    start_year_str = date(latest_product_date.year, 1, 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  

    # determine qtd start
    if latest_product_date.month in [1, 2, 3]:
        qtd_mth = 1
    elif latest_product_date.month in [4, 5, 6]:
        qtd_mth = 4
    elif latest_product_date.month in [7, 8, 9]:
        qtd_mth = 7
    elif latest_product_date.month in [10, 11, 12]:
        qtd_mth = 10

    start_qtd_str = date(latest_product_date.year, qtd_mth, 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       
    queryset_portfolio = ViewDashboard.objects.values('portfolio').annotate(
      base_lmv=Sum(Case(
        When(position_date__range=[latest_product_date_str, latest_product_date_str], then=F('base_lmv')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )),    
       day_product=Sum(Case(
        When(position_date__range=[latest_product_date_str, latest_product_date_str], then=F('base_daily_product')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )),        mtd_product=Sum(Case(
        When(position_date__range=[start_mth_str, latest_product_date_str], then=F('base_daily_product')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )),
      qtd_product=Sum(Case(
          When(position_date__range=[start_qtd_str, latest_product_date_str], then=F('base_daily_product')),
          default=Value(0),
          output_field=CharField(),
      )),
      ytd_product=Sum(Case(
        When(position_date__range=[start_year_str, latest_product_date_str], then=F('base_daily_product')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )),
     itd_product=Sum(Case(
        When(position_date__range=[start_itd_str, latest_product_date_str], then=F('base_daily_product')),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=CharField(),
    ))
    )           
   
    product_portfolio = SummaryproductPortfolioTable(queryset_portfolio)   
        

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)    

        context['latest_product_date'] = self.latest_product_date          
        context['product_portfolio'] = self.product_portfolio         
        
        return context
        
        
class ViewDashboard(models.Model):   
    unqiue_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)    
    partners_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    base_daily_product = models.FloatField(default=0)
    position_date = models.DateField()    
    product_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    book_id = models.IntegerField()
    book = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    portfolio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    analyst = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    base_lmv = models.FloatField(default=0)
   
    class Meta: 
        managed = False       
        db_table = 'view_dashboard_product_exposures'

I am at a loss as what to look at next. The session IDs don't seem to change after a GUNICORN restart so I don't think its related to this.
Where could this be failing?

"This doesn't seem to be applied when viewing in the browser". If you see that no-cache header in network tools then it must have been applied. You can confirm this by seeing if a subsequent navigation to the page sends a new network request or not. If it does then it must be the application that's serving the stale data. Perhaps somewhere in your application you're saving local state (backend caching? a variable?).

@KevinChristopherHenry thanks - I have added to the question the Python code of the View and the Model. Following your comments it seems to be something with the queryset not updating.

Why are you creating your querysets and running all of those queries on the class definition? Run the queries in a method in the class, a queryset only makes a DB query once (unless you call .all() on it, forcing a new queryset).
